# How to get bitmap information from onActivityResult and use it in the same activity

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I get bitmap image from gallery using   **protected void onActivityResult** .
 Now I want to get the information of this bitmap image to use it in another method in the same activity .
 This my code:
I get bitmap image from gallery using protected void onActivityResult . Now I want to get the information of this bitmap image to use it in another method in the same activity . This my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int selected_image = 1;
Bitmap bitmap;
ImageView imagev;
public static int n, m;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imagev = findViewById(R.id.imagev);
}


public void btnselectimage(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, selected_image);
    // I want get the width and height of this image here;
    System.out.println("width=" + n);
    System.out.println("height=" + m);
}


//  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case selected_image:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
                n = bitmap.getWidth();
                m = bitmap.getHeight();
                //  Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
                imagev.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    Bitmap bitmap;
    if (mImageViewer.getDrawable() instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mImageViewer.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    } else {
       imageView.invalidate();
       BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
       bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
    }
```

Comment: what does **mImageViewer** mean?

Comment: @sudadnajim its imageview ID.

Answer (score 1):

Once you set bitmap to image, You can get the bitmap attached to the same `ImageView` in different method like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imagev.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Comment: i can't get bitmap information outside ** OnActivityResult**, can you update my code please?

Comment: I've updated my answer. The image is actually the imageview in your xml file.

Comment: @sudadnajim You already have the bitmap in a global variable. You can use it anywhere in this activity. What do you mean by you "can't get bitmap information outside ** OnActivityResult**" . Use the "bitmap" variable outside anywhere to access it.

Comment: @Ravi When I tried to **get width** and **get height  inside **OnActivityResult** the result was right, but when i tried the same** outside **OnActivityResult** the result  was zero .

Comment: @sudadnajim Please update the code your question to help you

Comment: @sudadnajim You cannot print the width, height immediately in the next line. `startActivityForResult` will give you the result in `onActivityResult`. So, you have to wait till you get a bitmap in onActivtyresult and update the values from there.

Comment: @Ravi , thank you fro interest , can you explain your idea by code line?

Comment: @3iL, where i can use this line code , inside or outside  **startActivityForResult**

Comment: @sudadnajim You have to understand that any operations you want to do on image to get its width and height , should be done only after you get it. And, you are getting the image in **OnActivityResult** . so perform your operations from here.

Comment: @Ravi, thank you very much , my problem solved by getting information after view the image in image view , but that force me to put two buttons